# Load csv into array of dictionary using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

My knowledge of JavaScript is limited, but I am wanting to load a CSV file into an array of dictionaries. I have attached an example of the style that I am after, however, this would have to be dynamically changed as some tables could be quite large?

Example CSV:

```
Vehicle ID, Vehicle Name, Category, KM
0001, Yaris, commute, 12560
0002, z350, personal, 5600
0003, Porche, business, 21040
```

Example Array:

```
var vehicles = [
        {
            "Vehicle ID": "0001",
            "Vehicle Name": "Yaris",
            "Category": "commute",
            "KM": "12560.00"
        },
        {
            "Vehicle ID": "0002",
            "Vehicle Name": "Z350",
            "Category": "personal",
            "KM": "5600.09"
        },
        {
            "Vehicle ID": "0003",
            "Vehicle Name": "Porche",
            "Category": "business",
            "KM": "21040.70"
        }
    ];
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: is the CSV hosted on the same site as the web page? Or are yo asking how to convert CSV to javascript object? For the latter I recommend http://papaparse.com/ rather than writing your own csv parser

Comment: @JaromandaX I am creating a document automation program using HTML and JavaScript to style the PDF. So, the CSV file is in the same directory as the scripts. I am rendering the HTML to PDF using PhantomJS

Comment: right, so you're asking how to load the file, not how to parse it?

Comment: @JaromandaX, yes just loading it. Once I have it in the format I want, then I can deal with it. Just trying to figure that out.

Comment: @matoneski - Do you need sort values or sum? I ask for deleted question.

Comment: @jezrael I was looking to take the top four values and add the sum to a new column. You link helped with that. Thanks. I deleted due to a duplicate answer that I overlooked.

Comment: @jezrael I noticed that the solution was using NumPy. I have undeleted the question and will add some more details about expected output. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if I got you, this is what you need

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="app-wrapper">
    <div>
      <label for="file">Search File </label>
      <input type="file" id="file">
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>


    (function () {
  var fileInput = document.querySelector('#file');
  var reader = new FileReader ();
  fileInput.addEventListener('change', readCSVFile);
  reader.addEventListener('loadend', processData);

  function readCSVFile (e) {
    reader.readAsText(e.target.files[0]);
  }



  function processData() {
    var allTextLines = reader.result.split(/\r\n|\n/);
    var headers = allTextLines[0].split(',');
    var lines = [];

    for (var i=1; i<allTextLines.length; i++) {

        var data = allTextLines[i].split(',');
        if (data.length == headers.length) {
            var row = {};
            for (var j=0; j< headers.length; j++) {
               row[headers[j].trim()] = data[j].trim();

            }
            lines.push(row);
        }
    }
    console.log(lines);
  }

})();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

You can check it in this [link](https://jsbin.com/qicoyahufa/edit?js,console,output)

Comment: thanks for your answer. It is close enough to what I want. I just don't need to input file option in HTML. I am looking at populating a dynamic table with the function output and printing the HTML as a PDF using PhantomJS.

Comment: The console output is exactly what I am after. Thanks for that, I will just work around loading the file without an input field. Cheers.